# No overload for 'button1_Click' matches delegate

Tags: c#, button, event-handling, overloading

I don't understand why I get this error... Can anyone help me?

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, string filePath)
    {
        OpenFileDialog of = new OpenFileDialog();
        of.ShowDialog();
        Filenametext.Text = of.FileName;
        //Create an instance for the openbox dialog
        //And opens the explorer to select the wanted file.

        {

            DataRow row;
            DataService m_WsData = new DataService();


            string XMLFileName = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["XMLPath"].ToString() + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".xml";
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));

            {
                DataSet ds = m_WsData.GEDS();


                string line = "";

                int lineNo = 0;
                string lineStart = "";
                string lineEnd = "";
                string[] fileRow;

                {
                    line = sr.ReadLine();
                    if (line != null)
                    {
                        fileRow = line.Split(new Char[] { ';' });

                        if (lineNo == 0)
                        {
                            lineStart = fileRow[0];
                        }
                        if (fileRow[0] != "00" && fileRow[0] != "99")
                        {
                            row = ds.Tables["FuelFileData"].NewRow();
                            row["TransNo"] = fileRow[0];
                            row["CustomerNo"] = fileRow[1];
                            row["TruckNo"] = fileRow[2];
                            row["FuelDate"] = fileRow[3];
                            row["FuelTime"] = fileRow[4];
                            row["Place"] = fileRow[5];
                            row["FuelTypeNo"] = fileRow[6];
                            row["FuelDescription"] = fileRow[7];
                            row["DriverNo"] = fileRow[8];
                            row["Blank"] = fileRow[9];
                            row["TransType"] = fileRow[10];
                            row["Fuel"] = fileRow[11];
                            row["FuelCost"] = fileRow[12];
                            row["MileageFile"] = fileRow[13];
                            row["DrivenKm"] = fileRow[14];
                            row["AverageConsFile"] = fileRow[15];
                            //row["ImportedGuid"]=fileRow[16];


                        }
                        lineEnd = fileRow[0];
                        lineNo++;
                    }
                } while (line != null);

                lineStart = lineStart.Trim() + lineEnd.Trim();

                fs.Close();

                if (lineStart == "0099")
                {
                    ds.WriteXml(XMLFileName);
                    System.IO.File.Delete(XMLFileName);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: because your filelocation parameter, you can not add parameters to event handler

Comment: `string filePath` cannot be added here please remove it :)

Answer (score 0):

### Cause

You cannot add parameters on event handler methods.
The `Click` event is defined as

```
public event RoutedEventHandler Click;
```

which means that the handler must match the delegate `RoutedEventHandler` which is

```
public delegate void RoutedEventHandler(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e);
```

### Solution

Remove the `string filePath` parameter and pass the path via a public property.